# Stackoverflow Careers: How many applications Company receives and how many employees actually get hired on average

Tags: discussion, reputation, stack-overflow-jobs

My question is : If I apply to XYZ company, how many other candidates apply for same job ? And how many vacancies are there for that job.

My confusion is : If there only one position for employee(only 1 employee is needed) which Ads at right corner appear ? I live in india so there must be 1.5 million developer applications a company get for 1 position only?

Please clarify as I also want to apply my reputation getting good job here on careers 2.0.

Thanks

Comment: We don't know how many positions any given company is going to hire for, nor how many applications they'll get for the position. You'll have to ask the company for that information, although they may not want to give you an answer.

Comment: @MartijnPieters , I mean just an average figure. If an ad is posted , on average, how many developers are they going to hire ?

Comment: I very much doubt that companies share that information with Careers 2.0. Every company is different, and uses job advertisements differently, and have different needs and expectations of the hiring process, *anyway*. You cannot apply statistics to specific companies and hope to take advantage of that when applying.

Comment: Please clarify and add more detail. As it stands, not really a strong questiom

Comment: @Coffee the question is clear !

Comment: @0____________0 seems odd, but it is not up to you to decide what is clear and what isn't.  If someone is telling you your question isn't clear, the appropriate response is to ask what isn't clear, not tell them they are wrong because you asked a clear question.

Comment: @psubsee2003 sorry, what do you think is missing from the question?

Comment: @0____________0 I have no idea, I'm not the one that made the comment.  you should be asking Coffee.

Comment: @Coffee , Sorry, what do you think is missing from the question?

Comment: Part of your question may be answered by the Careers [House Rules](https://careers.stackoverflow.com/house-rules): "One position and one location per job listing. Multiple positions need to go into multiple job listings."

Answer (score 4):

Unless the recruiting company says how many of a particular position they are looking to fill in their advert, there is no way to know. You can usually assume that it's going to be at least one, though.

The "Apply Now" button is usually just a link to the application page on the recruiters' website. SE may track this internally, but it's competitively sensitive information for them so they're unlikely to make it publically available.